# Click Action not Working on Button - Java and Android Studio

Tags: java, android, mobile

I feel like an idiot for having to ask this, but I am working on a simple application that requires login. If the correct credentials are entered, it redirects to the settings/preferences activity. If not, it displays an error. Simple, right? However, I whenever I click the button, nothing happens.

login.java

```
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class login extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText userName;
    EditText password;
    Boolean verified = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userNameField);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordField);

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if ((userName.getText().toString() != "bkAdmin") || (password.getText().toString() != "midAmBK")) {
                    verified = false;
                } else {
                    verified = true;
                }
            }
        });
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("config.xml", MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (verified) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, midamcorp.com.burgerkingapp.preferences.class);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("loggedIn", true);
            editor.commit();
            if (preferences.getBoolean("config", false)) {
                editor.putBoolean("config", true);
                editor.commit();
            }
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Invalid Username or Password");

            builder.setPositiveButton("Accept", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

content_login.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="midamcorp.com.burgerkingapp.login"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_login">
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableRow android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="200dp"
            android:text=" Username:" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/userNameField"
        android:minWidth="200dp"
       />

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="200dp"
            android:text=" Password:" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"

        android:minWidth="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/passwordField"
/>
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:text = "Login!" />

</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I truly, truly appreciate any help!

Comment: why you haven't given width and height attribute for button??

Comment: Does it need to be `findViewById(R.id.loginButton)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write the code for navigating to the settings screen or showing the error dialog inside `OnClickListener`. At present it is outside it. Try this -

```
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class login extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText userName;
    EditText password;
    Boolean verified = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userNameField);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordField);
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if ((userName.getText().toString() != "bkAdmin") || (password.getText().toString() != "midAmBK")) {
                    verified = false;
                } else {
                    verified = true;
                }

 SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("config.xml", MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (verified) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(login.this, midamcorp.com.burgerkingapp.preferences.class);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("loggedIn", true);
            editor.commit();
            if (preferences.getBoolean("config", false)) {
                editor.putBoolean("config", true);
                editor.commit();
            }
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(login.this);
            builder.setMessage("Invalid Username or Password");

            builder.setPositiveButton("Accept", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });

        }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you much. It seems many suggest a similar solution. However, I run into another issue when I put the logic inside the click handler - the this keyword (for the intent and AlertDialog.Builder no longer works)? What do I use instead?

Comment: Replace "this" by "login.this" . The errors will get resolved. Edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the assistance; however, it still does not work. Any other ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: Now what's the issue ?

Comment: It is the same issue as the first, it simply does not respond.

Comment: Try adding multiple logs at different places in onClick()  and trace what is the flow. Use Log.d();

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it too work partially. Now the problem is that no matter what I do, it does not verify the credentials as correct. Verified always gets set to false when the button is clicked. Any ideas why?

Comment: Change if ((userName.getText().toString() != "bkAdmin") || (password.getText().toString() != "midAmBK")) {  BY  if ((!userName.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("bkAdmin") || (!password.getText().toString() .equalsIgnoreCase( "midAmBK")) {

Comment: That worked. Thank you so, so much! I genuinely appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. wrap you code in a method and call it inside your button click event.

```
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if ((userName.getText().toString() != "bkAdmin") || (password.getText().toString() != "midAmBK")) {
                    verified = false;
                } else {
                    verified = true;
                }
                completeRegistration(verified);
            }
        });
}
```

Wrap this in a method

```
private void completeRegistration(boolean verified){
        if (verified) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, midamcorp.com.burgerkingapp.preferences.class);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("loggedIn", true);
            editor.commit();
            if (preferences.getBoolean("config", false)) {
                editor.putBoolean("config", true);
                editor.commit();
            }
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Invalid Username or Password");

            builder.setPositiveButton("Accept", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The onCreate method is where you initialize the activity. Your verified variable will always be false. The callback of button click is executed after the onCreate was finished. Move your logic to other method or put inside the button callback.

Answer (score 0):

Use View.OnClickListener instead of Button.onClickListener